# How to remove JQuery from the Window/make the GC take it

Tags: javascript, jquery, garbage-collection, mootools

I have a page, when loaded it does some stuff with JQ.
In the next phase I want to load mootools and remove all JQ stuff, to avoid collisions and to avoid memory leaking.
I am not giving you the all picture (to simplify the question), but assume I am not doing something stupid here, and it needs to be done how I am asking it.

Comment: Maybe it's time to fix your code instead of adding another layer of hacks?

Comment: Please, again, you don't know the entire problem, you know what they say about assumptions...

Comment: @Itay - How can you say that to this comment, then respond to an answer saying "No collisions yes, but the current code base is so spaghetti that the browser will crash if I don't clean it completely."  ?  I have to agree with @jrockway, this isn't the appropriate solution and isn't fixing the real problem.

Comment: @Nick Craver I can't clean this code, it is not mine, I am not allowed to touch it, and if I was I will need several months to do so. Guys, really, why are you so interested in gossip, when what I search is a technical solution.

Comment: @Itay - What we're suggesting *is* the best technical solution.  Fixing the actual problem instead of working around it is almost always the best long-term solution.

Comment: @Nick Craver  - I agree with you 100%, BUT it is not possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has a [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) option to avoid collisions.. but I guess you could delete it...

```
delete window.jQuery;
delete window.$;//alias to jQuery
```

Comment: No collisions yes, but the current code base is so spaghetti that the browser will crash if I don't clean it completely. SO, this will also delete all the plugins? Are they under window.JQuery?

Comment: This would delete jQuery (the core library)... and any plugins that live within jQuery (e.g. extend it), but if they create their own globals, it won't delete them AFAIK.